# Linux BitTorrent client with support for magnet links

Tags: linux, bittorrent, magnet-links

Is there a Linux application (bonus points for being console/headless) that supports [magnet links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) - like the ones provided now by some famous "bay" for pirate BitTorrent users?

Comment: Magnet links are different?  I thought that they were the same as any other torrent, just linked from other trackers...

Comment: Yes. They are trackerless torrents, but require a different way of authenticating than traditional torrents

Comment: magnet links are not about being trackerless, they are about being .torrent less.  You can have a .torrent file that uses the DHT instead of a tracker.  magnet links take this one step further and do away with the .torrent file entirely.

Comment: I notice that the "headless" thing was mostly ignored. Did you find an actual solution? Deluge site doesn't mention feeding it magnet links with console- rather than X-based browsers. By now you clearly know that firefox-->vuze works for normal usage...

Comment: @Maggie: the accepted answer - rtorrent - is the one that I found the most useful. I run rtorrent on screen (well, actually tmux), and it doesn't require any kind of X environment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[rTorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTorrent) has support for [magnet links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) since *[v0.8.7 released in October 2010](http://rakshasa.no/pipermail/libtorrent-devel/2010-October/002539.html)*. To load one, just hit <kbd>backspace</kbd> in rTorrent and paste the magnet information.

---

The information provided below is three years old and outdated.

Maybe the tutorial *[How To Compile rTorrent From SVN In Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala / Debian 5 Lenny With Magnet Link Support](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-compile-rtorrent-from-svn-in-ubuntu-9.10-karmic-koala-debian-5-lenny-with-magnet-link-support)* will help you.

Comment: magnets arnt supported till rtorrent 0.8.7 but 0.8.7 doesnt work with rutorrent...

Answer (score 8):

Also, [Transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_(BitTorrent_client)) development version 1.80b1 supports magnet links. See [changes](http://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Changes#version-1.80b1).

Comment: BitTorrent Information Hierarchy(`xt=btih` or `at=btih`) only. No other topic types supported.

Answer (score 7):

[Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org) 1.1.9 supports magnet.

> Deluge is a full-featured  BitTorrent client for Linux, OS X, Unix and Windows. It uses  libtorrent in it's backend and features multiple user-interfaces including: GTK+, web and console. It has been designed using the client server model with a daemon process that handles all the bittorrent activity. The Deluge daemon is able to run on headless machines with the user-interfaces being able to connect remotely from any platform.

Comment: Deluge works as a server which has several clients that connect to it, this is specially good for depesz because there are at least 3 clients. One written in GTK, another is web based, and the third runs on the console.

Comment: [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org) supports magnet links. It also has headless operation and a WebUI, it is like uTorrent. But you must teach Firefox/Chromium whatever browser you use or xdg-open about how to open Magnet links.

Answer (score 2):

- [Transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_(BitTorrent_client))
- [Azureus / Vuze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuze)
- [rTorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTorrent)
- [KTorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KTorrent)
- [Deluge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deluge_(software))

Here's a useful script to enable magnet URLs in Firefox and Chrome / xdg-open:

http://sam.nipl.net/code/nipl-tools/bin/magnet-enable

For example:

```
./magnet-enable vuze
```

Answer (score 1):

Azureus has support for magnet links.

Answer (score 1):

The new [Transmission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_%28BitTorrent_client%29) version (1.82) accepts magnet links. It works fine!

Answer (score 1):

[KTorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KTorrent), as far as I know, supports them.

Answer (score 0):

With [Transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_(BitTorrent_client)) it is very simple. Just go to that "bay" and copy the magnet link address. Then in Transmission go to file->Open URL and paste it there. :)

Comment: Note that the OPś question was made 5 years ago. Transmission did not support magnet links then.

Answer (score -2):

***HEADLESS OPERATION WORKS!***

The problem we faced lies in the instability of older versions of [rTorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTorrent) and [libtorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libtorrent). rTorrent 0.8.9 and libtorrent 0.12.9 are stable and will correctly load magnet links if the magnet link is wrapped as given by the script provided by rTorrent.

As far as I know, rTorrent is the only client that can handle magnet links dropped in to the client as easily as torrents.